# Cross Entropy Error remains unchanged for various values

Tags: neural-network, classification, conv-neural-network, softmax, cross-entropy

I am using Cross Entropy with Softmax as loss function for my neural network.
The cross entropy function I have written is as follows:

```
def CrossEntropy(calculated,desired):
    sum=0
    n=len(calculated)
    for i in range(0,n):
        sum+=(desired[i] * math.log(calculated[i])) + ((1-desired[i])* math.log(1-calculated[i]))

    crossentropy=(-1)*sum/n
    return crossentropy
```

Now let us suppose the **desired output is [1,0,0,0]** and we are testing it for **two calculated outputs i.e. a=[0.1,0.9,0.1,0.1]** and **b=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.9]**. **The problem is that for both these calculated outputs will  the function would return the exact same value for cross entropy.** So how does the neural network learn that which output is the correct one ?

Comment: It's covered by backpropagatioin.

Comment: Your CE is for binary classificiation, ie you have 2 output classes. For your sample, as you have 4 the above CE is incorrect. You should do: - sum(desired * log(calculated))

Answer (score 0):

That is expected because you have a **data symmetry** in your two `calculated` cases.

In your example, the desired output is `[1, 0, 0, 0]`. Thus the true class is the first class. However, in both `a` and `b` your prediction for the first class are the same (0.1). Also for other classes (true negatives - 2nd, 3rd and 4th class),  you have this data symmetry (class 2 and class 4 are equally important with respect to the loss calculation).

```
 a -> 0.9,0.1,0.1
       ^
       |       |
               V
 b -> 0.1,0.1,0.9
```

Thus you have the same loss which is expected.

If you remove this symmetry, you get different cross entropy loss. See examples below:

```py
# The first two are from your examples.
print CrossEntropy(calculated=[0.1,0.9,0.1,0.1], desired=[1, 0, 0, 0])
print CrossEntropy(calculated=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.9], desired=[1, 0, 0, 0])

# below we have prediction for the last class as 0.75 thus break the data symmetry.
print CrossEntropy(calculated=[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.75], desired=[1, 0, 0, 0])

# below we have prediction for the true class as 0.45.
print CrossEntropy(calculated=[0.45,0.1,0.1,0.9], desired=[1, 0, 0, 0])


result:
1.20397280433
1.20397280433
0.974900121357
0.827953455132
```